# Schrödinger operator whose potential analytically depends on a parameter – how does the spectrum change?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let's say we have a self-adjoint operator $H_s$ on the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$
  H_s \, \psi(x) := -\psi''(x) + V_s(x) \, \psi(x) \: ,
$$
where $s \in \mathbb{R}$ is a free parameter and the real function $V_s(x)$ is analytic in $s$. Let's also suppose that the spectrum of $H_s$ is discrete for every $s$. What can we say about the eigenvalues and their dependence on $s$? Do they change continuously with $s$, or even analytically?

---

I've tried searching for a relevant theorem in Kato's [Perturbation Theory](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf), but couldn't find it. Any references are welcome!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann–Feynman_theorem

Comment: @KirylPesotski I know the [Hellmann–Feynman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem), but I'm afraid I don't know how to differentiate unbounded operators...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it *is* in Kato, as theorem VII.3.9 ...

... and, yes, the spectrum depends analytically on the parameter in which the coefficients are (real) analytic.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @m93a, good! you're welcome! :)